# when linking the objects, make reports: group ended before it began?

Tags: makefile

I need to link my objects to library files from others.
Thus, in my makefile, I write like this:

```
LIBSB =-Wl,--start-group -ldiag -ldiag_esw -lacl -ldiagcint -lcint -lsal_appl \
-lbcm_compat -lbcm_rpc -lcpudb  -ltrx  -lstktask -llubde -ldrivers -ldiscover  \
-lrcu -lpthread -lrt -lm   -Wl,--end-group
LIB :=  -L../lib/$(LIBSB)   # ../lib is the path of folder
APP_NAME = L3appl
$(APP_NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CC)   -c  $(INC_DIR) $(SRCS)
    $(CC)   -o  $(APP_NAME)  $(OBJS) $(LIB)
```

but the make reports:

```
group ended before it began (--help for usage)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [L3appl] Error 1
```

Is there someone know what's the matter with my makefile???
thx for your help!!!

Comment: Try inserting a space: `LIB :=  -L../lib/ $(LIBSB)`.

Answer (score 1):

change `LIB :=  -L../lib/$(LIBSB)` to  `LIB :=  -L../lib $(LIBSB)`