# Error when trying to specify the ldflags in a gyp file

Tags: linker, makefile, shared-libraries, gyp

I am trying to create a makefile through GYP. I had errors saying that ld cannot find the necessary libraries so I included them in ldflags in the gyp file. The code I have is:

```
'link_settings': {
        'ldflags': [
          '-L/path/to/lib1' , '-L/path/to/lib2', ...
        ],
        'libraries': [
          '-llib1',
          '-llib2', ...
        ],
      },
```

The previous errors dissappeared, but now I am getting a new one

```
group ended before it began (--help for usage)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried adding the libraries in the 'libraries' list with an absolute path but the result is the same. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920178/when-linking-the-objects-make-reports-group-ended-before-it-began) question but I don't thing it helps me (or I can't understand how). I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this error by specifying the exact libraries that I wanted to include from each directory:

```
'ldflags': [
      '-L/path/to/lib1 -llib1' , '-L/path/to/lib2 -llib2', ...
    ],
```